# Where is an applet trying to load a class from?

Tags: java, http, applet, classloader

I'm trying to debug an applet that occasionally fails with the stack trace below (on the Java Console).

It looks like it's trying to load binaries and it's getting an HTTP REDIRECT which isn't legal (perhaps because of the applet sandbox?).

Is there any way to turn on verbose class loading output (or other debugging that might be useful) on the Java Console?  If this were a standard Java application (as opposed to an applet), I would put "-verbose:class" on the command line and see what I get - but I don't know how to do that with an applet.

I don't have access to the source for the applet - so I can't add any kind of instrumentation to the code itself.

> java.lang.SecurityException: illegal URL redirect
>               at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
>               at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
>               at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
>               at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.isUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
>               at com.sun.deploy.cache.DeployCacheHandler.get(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.downloadJAR(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.access$000(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack$2.run(Unknown Source)
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>               at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFileInternal(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$800(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>               at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>               at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
>               at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
>               at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>               at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: illegal URL redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `-verbose:class` to the command line of java by going to Control Panel, Java, Java, View, then editing the 'runtime parameters'.

Answer (score 0):

To make your applet get sources NOT FROM its native host you have to sign it;

[Here are some helpful tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/index.html)

---

Report that helps